# Display only the columns needed PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have to display four columns but three of them each time, the column reference doesn't need to be displayed for a problem of space. This code allows to display cells which aren't in the column reference. When the cells match, the cell in the other columns disappears.

file:

```
  ComputerName  OtherComputerName   OtherComputer   AndAgain
    infra-1     infra-852            infra-2        infra-99
    infra-98    infra-85             infra-44       infra-23
    infra-5     infra-8              infra-1        infra-10
    infra-2     infra-55             infra-8        infra-70
    infra-62    infra-5              infra-852      infra-5
```

script:

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\test1.csv -Delimiter ';'

$ref = @($csv.ComputerName)
foreach ($row in $csv) {
  foreach ($col in 'OtherComputerName', 'OtherComputer', 'AndAgain') {
    if ($ref -contains $row.$col) { $row.$col = '' }
  }
}

$csv
```

the result on PS: I would like to not display the ComputerName column and retire the space between the cells.

```
OtherComputerName OtherComputer AndAgain
----------------- ------------- --------
infra-852                       infra-99
infra-85          infra-44      infra-23
infra-8                         infra-10
infra-55          infra-8       infra-70
                  infra-852
```

the expected result:

```
OtherComputerName OtherComputer AndAgain
----------------- ------------- --------
infra-852         infra-44      infra-99
infra-85          infra-8       infra-23
infra-8           infra-852     infra-10
infra-55                        infra-70
```

Comment: Use `Where-Object` to filter output based on whatever criteria you want, and `Select-Object` to output only the columns you want.

Comment: Can you show me an example pls i'm a little bit lost. I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Your question is not clear on what conditions you are trying to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either list all columns/properties to include

```
$csv | Select-Object OtherComputerName,OtherComputer,AndAgain
```

or use `-ExcludeProperty` to remove named ones - but then there must be a least one -Property (position 0 doesn't have to be written out, simply use an asterisk for all)

```
$csv | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty ComputerName
```

Sample output here exactly matching your requirements:

```
OtherComputerName OtherComputer AndAgain
----------------- ------------- --------
infra-852                       infra-99
infra-85          infra-44      infra-23
infra-8                         infra-10
infra-55          infra-8       infra-70
                  infra-852
```

Not a table but a single shrinked col:

```
$csv|select Othercomputer|where Othercomputer -ne ''
```

Sample output:

```
OtherComputer
-------------
infra-44
infra-8
infra-852
```

Comment: When I exclude the column there still a big space between some cells. Is it possible to retire it ?

Comment: Append `|Format-Table -auto`

Comment: `$csv | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty ComputerName |Format-Table -auto` like this ? If it is, it does nothing

Comment: The columns can't be smaller than the headings.

Comment: So, It is impossible to exclude cells which are matching with the first column ?

Comment: It is, I generated a source file where the empty cells were replaced with the ComputerNames and your script did well. Now I see your source seems to have spaces as delimiters?

Comment: Without this it would be an ugly table with ';' everywhere. I would like to exclude the cells which are matching with the cells of the ComputerName Column and reduce the size of the table with extracting of the matching cells

Comment: That last now understood requirement is difficul to realize, it's no table anymore but three independent lists in table form.

Comment: Is it doable ? With the actual code or shall restart from scratch ?

Comment: Depends on where the source data stems from and how repetitive the task is. Iterating the rows and cols to check if empty and exchange with the next value in the same col is tedious.

Comment: I have to do that for four columns with approximately 220 rows each one but I have no idea how to do this, I watched the other questions but it doesn't help me anymore

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: Well, the most welcome thank is check marking the answer ;-)

Comment: I have a last question. How to make this with four different 'where'?Because I tried in the same line but it display nothing so I don't know how to make that work

Answer (score 0):

This should do your work:

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\test1.csv -Delimiter ';'

$ref = @($csv.ComputerName)
foreach ($row in $csv) {
  foreach ($col in 'OtherComputerName', 'OtherComputer', 'AndAgain') {
    if ($ref -contains $row.$col) { $row.$col = '' }
  }
}

$csv | Select-Object ComputerName , AndAgain
```