# Get many lists in the same output with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have to display this in the blue part of the ISE :

```
Column1   Column2   Column3   Column4
-------   -------   -------   -------
infra-98 infra-852 infra-44  infra-99
infra-62 infra-85  infra-8   infra-23
         infra-8   infra-852 infra-10
         infra-55            infra-70


Column1   Column2    Column3    Column4
-------   -------    -------    -------
infra-1   infra-85   infra-2     infra-99
infra-98  infra-55   infra-44    infra-23
infra-2              infra-1     infra-10
infra-62                         infra-70
```

the csv file (excel table) (note: the stars are the matching cells:

```
Column1      Column2    Column3     Column4
*infra-1*    infra-85  *infra-2*    infra-99
infra-98     infra-85   infra-44    infra-23
*infra-5*    infra-8   *infra-1*    infra-10
*infra-2*    infra-55   infra-8     infra-70
infra-62    *infra-5*   infra-852   *infra-5*
*infra-6*   *infra-6*   infra-853   *infra-6*
```

Firstly, there is four lists which displays the cells not matching with the Column1 and then in the second one we have the same thing for the Column2. The problem is that I don't know how to do that. People told me this is doable but complex to make so is there another option to create this ?

The current code allows to remove the cells which aren't matching with the first column:

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\test1.csv -Delimiter ';'

$ref = @($csv.Column1)
foreach ($row in $csv) {
  foreach ($col in 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4') {
    if ($ref -contains $row.$col) { $row.$col = '' }
  }
}


$csv | Select-Object Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4
```

Comment: I just want to have the output up there but my current code is not made for this, I don't know what to do the 2 tables up must be in the same output

Comment: Yes because I don't know what shall I do to be able to display the expected output. I just want to have this output by every means. I trying to explain it in the question

Comment: It took a lot of comments in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633430/display-only-the-columns-needed-powershell) to understand that charlo wants to shift up entries in each separate column so that there are no more gaps.

Comment: Sry, i can't explain correctly my problems even if i read the tutorial but this is more simple to explain this orally. I'm a little bit stressed because I have to finish that in two weeks.

Comment: @wOxxOm yes there the `*` are removed in the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build 4 separate arrays, one for each column, then join:

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\1.csv -Delimiter ';'

$ref = [ordered]@{}
$columns = foreach ($i in 0..3) { ,[Collections.ArrayList]@() }

foreach ($row in $csv) {
    $value = $row.Column1
    $ref[$value] = $true
    $columns[0].add($value) >$null
}

foreach ($row in $csv) {
    $i = 1
    foreach ($col in 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4') {
        $value = $row.$col
        if (!$ref[$value]) {
            $columns[$i].add($value) >$null
        }
        $i++
    }
}

$maxLine = ($columns | select -expand Count | measure -Maximum).Maximum - 1
$csv = foreach ($i in 0..$maxLine) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Column1 = $columns[0][$i]
        Column2 = $columns[1][$i]
        Column3 = $columns[2][$i]
        Column4 = $columns[3][$i]
    }
}
```

This is a generic example so you will probably need to adjust it.

Comment: Some cells have diseppeared for no reason.

Comment: I know that but it's just a question. My objective is compound of two parts. First remove the mtching cells and second display many tables/lists or whatever in the same output, this is what i was asking for.

Comment: How would I know? I don't know what the error is, what your actual data is, and so on.

Comment: It's ok I found it there was a problem with the values everything is ok, thanks